# Jquery UI resizable not working with ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, ckeditor

I'm trying to use the inline editing functionality of `ckeditor` on a div that is made draggable and resizable using `jquery-ui`. Initially the drag and resize functions work perfectly. But once the `ckeditor` is initialised resizing stops working ( on clicking the div itself it turns into editor).

On inspecting elements the `ui-resize` class is still present. How can I make both functionalities work together ?

Here is the code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#sample").draggable({
    containment: "#container"
  });
  $("#sample").resizable({
    containment: "#container",
    handles: 'all'
  });
  var editor = CKEDITOR.inline('sample');
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #444;
}
#sample {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.2/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.2/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNjb53/rY+WmG+4L6tTl9m6PpqknWZvRt0rO1SRnJzw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="container">


  <div id="sample" contenteditable="true">
    There is some random text here
  </div>

</div>
```

For those who prefer jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/L8f0oxq1/

Comment: your cdn doesnt get the config [here is a working version](https://jsfiddle.net/zwa4b5bc/). also when you put containment and the container is the same size of the ckeditor you cant really do anything.

Comment: I'm looking to use the inline functionality. Its working fine with `replace` function. But not with `inline` , that is the real issue here.

Comment: Oh, okey. maybe try to apply draggable and resizable on an event or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle plz have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/RRR0308/L8f0oxq1/3/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="editor-container">
    <div id="sample">

    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#editor-container{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
#sample {
  height: 97%;
  width: 97%;
  z-index:999;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#editor-container").draggable({

        containment: "#container"
  });

  $("#editor-container").resizable({
    containment: "#container",
    handles: 'all'
  });

  $('#sample').click(function(){
    $("#sample").focus();
    console.log('clicked');
  });

  var editor = CKEDITOR.inline('sample');

});
```